# Volume of solid by revolution

Tags: solid-of-revolution

Find the volume generated by revolving the area bounded by the curves $(x^2+4a^2)y=8a^3, 2y=x$ and $x=0$, about the y axis.

To find volume I am using this formula:
$V=\pi\int [f(y)]^2dy$ where 
$f(y)= \sqrt{\frac{8a^3}{y}-4a^2}$

But how do I determine the limits of this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

from the first equation we have
$$
y=\frac{8a^3}{x^2+4a^2}
$$

substituting $x=0$ we find $y=2a$

substituting $x=2y$ we find $y=a$

and you have to divide the interval for $y$ in two parts:

$0<y<a$  and $a<y<2a$  ( for $a>0$)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make a drawing of the bounded area, you will see that, in the first quadrant,  $y=x/2$ is an increasing line from $(0,0)$ and $y=\frac{8a^3}{x^2+4a^2}$ is a decreasing curve from $(0,2a)$. Their intersection point is $(2a,a)$. So, it is better to split the integral into two pieces in the following way
$$V=\pi\int_{y=0}^a (2y)^2 dy+\pi\int_{y=a}^{2a} \left(\sqrt{\frac{8a^3}{y}-4a^2}\right)^2 dy.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Did you do this without tracing the curve or did you have an idea of what the curve would look like?

Comment: @user464068 Yes, I made a sketch: $y=x/2$ is an increasing line from $(0,0)$ and $y=\frac{8a^3}{x^2+4a^2}$ is a decreasing curve from $(0,2a)$. Their intersection point is $(2a,a)$.